# Android - How to Download XML Files with Android 4.0?

Tags: java, android, xml, download

I will Download XML File with Android 4.0 my old Code works at Android 2.3.3 here:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

I must have an Example without DefaultHttpClient .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem may be the "strict mode" here.

you have to do http requests  with a thread or an AsyncTask.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             //http request here
            //return the response as string
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //set the the data you get
        }
```

then:

```
new RequestTask().execute(yourHttpRequestString)
```

Answer (score 1):

From Gingerbread (2.3) and up, the preferred method for retrieving HTTP data is HttpUrlConnection. You might wanna check [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for details. You may also want to check the [Javadoc for HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```